# Is there a way to add hyperlinks into Importxlm?

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have been trying to find a way to get hyperlinks added into the data pulled from a website. I have tried using //@href combining this into the formula, but have not had any success.
I have also tried pulling the URL from the website in a separate sheet to try and combine the 2 lots of data but again no success.
I'm sure there must be an easy solution to this but having minimal knowledge on excel has made it tricky!

The link to a copy of the spreadsheet is below, and the formula I am currently using to pull data into google sheets is below but has no URL attached to the information when pulled.

`=transpose(IMPORTXML(B1,"//div[@id='page-box']/div[2]/ section/div"))`

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hiQ5EeGEgQC7kPApCUyR3r_uZb31MVDzdiffqApDdGE/edit?usp=sharing

Hopefully someone can help with this solution. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=importxml(url,"//div[@class='alphabet__list-column']//a/@href")
```

[image]

### edit:

use following xpath

```
//span[@class='alphabet__list-letter']|//div[@class='alphabet__list-column']//a/@href
```

to retrieve also the letter

[image]

Comment: Thats great, really appreciated